# session.clear() detach reference entity and create new record

Tags: hibernate, session

**Item.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class Item extends Model {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", name = "parent_id")
    private Item parent;    
}
```

We are processing batch and save it to database. In that batch we've `Item`s that has parent attached to it as follow

```
Item[id=null] {child1}
    -> ParentItem[id=null] {parent1}
```

Now `session.save(item);` called which generated following ids.

```
Item[id=129123] {child1}
    -> ParentItem[id=129122] {parent1}
```

Now `session.flush();` and `session.clear();` called.

In that batch we've another `Item` that has same parent attached to it.

```
Item[id=null] {child2}
    -> ParentItem[id=null] {parent1 same object attached in child1}
```

Technically `child2` should refer parent {`ParentItem[id=129122]`} created in `child1`. But when I call `session.save(item);` on `child2` it creates new ParentItem.

```
Item[id=129125] {child2}
    -> ParentItem[id=129124] {parent1} // I want ParentItem[id=129122] should be here.
```

> Note: This happens because we called `session.clear();`.

We are using following code to save the records.

```
IntStream.range(0, items.size())
         .filter(i -> items.get(i) != null).forEach(i -> {
            T item = items.get(i);
            Item it = (Item) item;

            session.save(item);

            if (i % 50 == 0) {
                session.flush();
                session.clear();
            }
         });
tr.commit();
```

**Questions:**

- We should call `session.clear();` after saving all Objects?
- If `session.clear();` called on reference entity than Hibernate can't identify object attached to other object. [Is Hibernate's rule or we are missing some Hibernate configuration]

**Possible Solution:**

- After reading couple of articles they suggest use `StatelessSession`.

What you suggest?

### **Edit:**

---

I used `StatelessSession#insert` then it throws following exception. It means we've to save attached parent item explicitly(We don't want this) so is there any other way?

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.org.openxcell.model.Item
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:537)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2843)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2818)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister$4.bindValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3025)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
    at org.hibernate.internal.StatelessSessionImpl.insert(StatelessSessionImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.internal.StatelessSessionImpl.insert(StatelessSessionImpl.java:123)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a OneToOne mapping. If you want to have many items with same parent you must use ManyToOne mapping.

Comment: One `Item` can have only one parent `Item`. How to map `ManyToOne` relationship for self `Entity`. If we've another `Entity` child then we can map it `ManyToOne`

Comment: Maybe I'm seeing it wrong but if you have two different items with the same parent you need a ManyToOne relationship regardless of being a self reference or a reference to another entity.